# Каков русский аналог понятия "портфолио"?

Tags: семантика, общие-вопросы

На самом деле правильнее было бы сформулировать вопрос примерно так: "За какое место следует подвесить министра, утвердившего в программе первого класса (!) предмет *Портфолио*?". Потому что в этом контексте перевод предмета на русский должен звучать как "**Я**". Или даже как "**Я - самый крутой!**".

Наших детей с семи лет стремительным домкратом впихивают в плоскость "борьбы за существование". Ведь если бы у этой ... дешёвой "программы" были более-менее мирные намерения, предмет бы назвали как-нибудь вроде "Мой дневник" или там "Я и моя семья". А так - налицо *программирование* в совершенно определённом направлении. Я не прав?

upd 2013-09-24 ===

Я не против того, чтобы ребёнок отмечал в дневнике свои достижения и радовался им - как мы радуемся, отмечая его рост зарубками на дверном косяке.

Я против того, чтобы моёго ребёнка с детства учили продавать себя, распихивая других локтями. Я против именно наименования - вектора "портфолио".

Потому что "... в бизнесе никогда не следует проявлять поспешности, иначе сильно сбавляешь цену, а это глупо: продавать самое святое и высокое надо как можно дороже, потому что потом торговать будет уже нечем". (с)

Comment: *Что у вас, робяты, в портфелЯх?*

Comment: Можно найти первоисточник новости о Министре и портфолио?
Немного порылся - ничего похожего.  
Напоминает обычный развод...

Comment: @behemothus, в 1 классе, где учится мой ребёнок, есть предмет "Портфолио". По содержанию: создание аппликаций из семейных фото, оценка "что я могу и чего не могу" - т.е. вполне полезная вещь. 

Моя претензия - к наименованию предмета. И к министру. Я не знаю, в школе, в нашем городе или в Москве это название придумали, но претензия - к министру. По принципу "отвечает всегда старший".

Но в свете ответа Людмилы я начинаю сомневаться насчёт министра - вполне могла быть самодеятельность конкретной школы под давлением родителей. Похоже, наш народ имеет ровно таких правителей, которых заслуживает.

Answer (score 3):

Вы бы сначала спросили, что делают на этом предмете. В нашей школе такого предмета нет, но я бы не против, чтобы его ввели. Коли такое нововведение появилось, пусть бы на отдельном уроке учитель  с детьми и занимался бы составлением портфолио(портфеля достижений), а то всё перекладывается на плечи родителей.Родители вынуждены тратить время и силы на портфолио ребёнка, чтобы он не выглядел "хуже других".Уж пусть бы занимались этим на уроке.И обсуждали его,защищали, подводили итоги.Что-то вроде классного часа. Почему бы и нет? А что это сложно, с этим столкнулись уже все.Это не борьба за существование, это развитие творческих способностей. Никто никого не ругает, если у него нет достижений, хвалят того, у кого они есть, а остальные подтянутся, если есть гордость и чувство лидерства, а нет - и не надо.У каждого свой характер. Вот, думаю, удачный пример работы с портфолио: http://schooln9.ru/articles/works-of-pupils/uchebnoe-portfolio-kak-vid-kontrolno-ocenochnoj-deyatelnosti

Comment: Довольно обидные ваши слова, @Людмила. Если бы я не делал сам со своей дочерью это с... самое портфолио, то и вопроса бы не было.

> силы на портфолио ребёнка, чтобы он не
> выглядел "хуже других".

Это и есть **программирование**, впихивание в плоскость товарно-денежных отношений. От природы ни один ребёнок не бывает "хуже других". Это вы их такими делаете, вслед за буржуями! (keep up Jhons)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема портфолио лежит даже не в области образования, а в смене установок менталитета. От коллектив>индивидуальности, до обратной модели.

Пораспрашивал подругу у которой ребёнок в 3 классе. Из-за портфолио учительницца задаёт массу заданий, в большинстве из которых победить без помощи родителей невозможно. Все задания противопоставляют учеников друг другу, но не обучают взаимодействию в группе. Что разительно отличется даже от обучения в 90-х, когда школьником был я. Кроме конкурсов чтецов и красоты, все соревнования были командными, хотя даже в них ты представлял в первую очередь свой класс, а уж потом себя.

Хорошо это или плохо сказать невозможно, и у той и у другой системы есть свои преимущества и недостатки. Но парадигма воспитывается совершенно иная, так что, боюсь, нам понимать своих подросших детей будет нелегко, хотя и это не ново.